# Conky for Google Calendar and Tasks?

Tags: gmail, conky, google-calendar

Currently, I'm using conky to display a big clock and that helps me a lot. Now, I am thinking it would be really cool if I can get the schedule and task list from Gmail and display them beautifully on conky. Is there anyone who develops such scripts or knows where to get one of those?

Thanks

Comment: try at deviantart, or gnome look sites.

Answer (score 3):

There is a script to get it working on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=837385).

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install conkygooglecalendar`

Add to your .conkyrc:

`${execpi 1800 conkyGoogleCalendar
--username=yourname@gmail.com --password=yourpassword --daysahead=30 --dateformat="%a %d %b, %y" --requestCalendarNames="MyCalendar1;MyCalendar2"
--template=~/scripts/conkyGoogleCalendar.template}`

Replace MyCalendar1 and MyCalendar2 with the name of your Calendar/Tasks.
Create a template, in this case there is a template in ~/scripts/ named conkyGoogleCalendar.template.
Example of this template:

${color4}${font Ubuntusize=10}Event: ${font Ubuntu:bold:size=10} ${color3}[title]

${color2}${font Ubuntu:size=8}Start:$font ${color1}[starttime]

${color2}${font Ubuntu:size=8}End:$font ${color1}[endtime]

${color2}${font Ubuntu:size=8}Description:$font ${color1}[description]

${color2}${font Ubuntu:size=8}Place:$font ${color1}[location]

You can take a look at the "Conky companions" [here](https://launchpad.net/~conky-companions/+archive/ppa/+packages).

There is a README file within the package with clear instructions.